# Schwarzschild metric - minimum rate of decreasing $r$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems

So in the Schwarzschild metric, I want to find the minimum rate at which the coordinate $r$ decreases for a massive particle wrt to the proper time (Ex 5.3 Carroll). The particle doesn't need to be in a geodesic and I consider the particle inside the horizon of the BH.  So I used the massive particle condition:

$$U^2=-1$$
and I got:

$$\left(\frac{d r}{d \tau}\right)^{2}=\left(\frac{2 G M}{r}-1\right)\left[1+\left(\frac{2 G M}{r}-1\right)\left(\frac{d t}{d \tau}\right)^{2}+r^{2}\left(\frac{d \Omega}{d \tau}\right)^{2}\right]$$
So now I can argue that motion along $\theta$ or $\phi$ is gonna increase the rate. So to find the minimum one I consider a radial motion:

$$\left(\frac{d r}{d \tau}\right)^{2}=\left(\frac{2 G M}{r}-1\right)\left[1+\left(\frac{2 G M}{r}-1\right)\left(\frac{d t}{d \tau}\right)^{2}\right]$$
At this point I would have the minimum rate for

$$\left(\frac{d t}{d \tau}\right)^{2} \rightarrow 0 $$
But what is the meaning of this limit? Can I actually take it?

Comment: *motion along  or  is gonna increase the rate* For $r>2GM$ the prefactor is negative, so that isn’t true.

Comment: When working outside the horizon, I recommend writing $1-2GM/r$ rather than $2GM/r-1$. Having fewer negative things is less confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I am studying a particle inside the horizon